# Poor man's double acute accent

Tags: accents

I want to typeset the double acute accent (also known as Hungarian umlaut, usually typeset with \H{}) in a font that does not have it. Is there an easy way to "fake" it with two single accents?

Minimial example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\augie}[1]{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont #1}
\begin{document}
\augie{Erdos Erd\'os Erd\H{o}s}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can switch font just for the accent then back to the text font so get a real `\H` accent from another font, but as this font is quite stylized it might look better to do as you say and use two acute accents from this font, you could adjust the spacing a bit more, but this shows the two approaches;

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\fakeH{\rlap{\'{}\'{}}}
\newcommand*{\augie}[1]{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont #1}
\begin{document}


\augie{Erdos Erd\'os  Erd\fakeH{o}s  Erd{\rmfamily\H{\augie o}}s}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe something like `\def\fakeH[1]{\rlap{\'{#1}\'{\phantom{#1}}}` could get the vertical spacing closer to right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm! I really should reread the relevant part of TeXbook.

Comment: @MikaelVejdemo-Johansson unfortunately you can't do box operations like phantom inside the accent command you get `! Improper \setbox.` error.

Comment: Bummer. Oh well, it was worth an idea at least. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a macro that tries a precise calculation based on the height of the character

```
\newcommand\fH[1]{\sbox0{#1}\dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 -1ex
  \sbox2{\'{}}\sbox2{\raise\dimen0\box2}%
  {\ooalign{\hidewidth\kern.1em\copy2\kern-.5\wd2\box2\hidewidth\cr\box0\crcr}}}
```

and the result of

```
Erd\fH{o}s

Erd\H{o}s

\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont

Erd\fH{o}s

Erd\'{o}s
```

[image]

Perhaps it's better to use `\kern-.5\wd2` for the augie font

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Defining new accents is difficult to get right. There is a package (not on ctan) described in  http://www.eutypon.gr/eutypon/pdf/e2000-05/e05-a04.pdf which you can try. The package can be found at https://github.com/zellyn/accentbx.

```
    \makeaccent[options]<shifts>{accent-character}{main-character}
```