# TIPA input for African language symbols

Tags: fonts, tipa

I am digitalizing the handwritten notes of some African languages through LaTex. I encountered several symbols and was not able to find TIPA code for them. I wonder how I can input them in LaTex. Many thanks!

[image: 1. "L"-like diacritics on an "u"; 2. right-sliding over macron tone symbol on an "e"; 3. right-sliding over macron tone symbol over two "a"s; 4. a barred a; 5. high tone symbol and low tone symbol on a single "a"; 6. a acute accent at the right-bottom of an "o"]

Comment: Are you already using TIPA for other characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols like this are not too difficult to compose from other symbols. Here's how I managed to do the ones you show. The barred vowel uses an existing TIPA command. The harpoon like elements I've added with the `harpoon` package, and the split grave/aigu accents I've adapted [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49321/2693) from [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{harpoon,MnSymbol}
\newcommand{\squareharp}[1]{\overharp{\invbackneg}{#1}{1}}
\newcommand{\textbara}{\ipabar{\tipaencoding A}{.5ex}{1}{-.1}{0}}
\newcommand{\harp}[1]{\overharp{\rightharpoonup}{#1}{1}}
\newcommand{\lowaigu}[1]{#1\kern-.2em\raisebox{-1.25ex}{\'{}}}
% Next command adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49321/2693
\newcommand{\GraveAigu}[1]{\sbox0{#1}\dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 -1ex
  \sbox2{\'{}}\sbox1{\`{}}\sbox2{\raise\dimen0\box2}%
  {\ooalign{\hidewidth\kern-.05em\copy1\kern-.65\wd2\box2\hidewidth\cr\box0\crcr}}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{IPA}
\squareharp{u}
\textbara{}
\harp{e}
\harp{aa}
\GraveAigu{u}
\lowaigu{o}
\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @mxue Note that to say 'thanks!' you can *accept* Alan's answer by clicking on the greyed-out tick/check mark at the top left of the answer. When you have more reputation, you can also vote for answers but you don't need any reputation to accept the answer which best solves the problem you asked about. In this case, you might prefer to wait to see if any later answers serve your purposes better, although sometimes an answer is so useful, you know none better will come along later!

Comment: @Alan Munn Thanks! I have another question. I used package semtrans for inputting \Alif, however, when I incorporated the command lines you suggested, it seems the semtrans is suppressed. It reports error on symbols of \Alif. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: @mxue I think you should ask this as a separate question. Few people will see it here in a comment. Remember to include a complete minimal (non)working example. You can link back to this question.