# New commands suppress other commands

Tags: macros, output, tipa

I adapted the new commands wrote by @Alan Munn, to produce LaTex representation for some African language symbols. However, the new commands seem to suppress the use of other symbols, which worked well before. The symbol did not work with the new commands is a backward c tone symbol, by using the package semtrans, TIPA code = `\Alif` A working example as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\begin{document}
\begin{IPA}
aa{\Alif}
\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

This example works fine as itself. If I incorporated the above code to @AlanMunn's commands, it was not able to recognize {\Alif}. The combined code as below:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepacakge{semtrans}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{harpoon,MnSymbol}
\newcommand{\squareharp}[1]{\overharp{\invbackneg}{#1}{1}}
\newcommand{\textbara}{\ipabar{\tipaencoding A}{.5ex}{1}{-.1}{0}}
\newcommand{\harp}[1]{\overharp{\rightharpoonup}{#1}{1}}
\newcommand{\lowaigu}[1]{#1\kern-.2em\raisebox{-1.25ex}{\'{}}}
% Next command adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49321/2693
\newcommand{\GraveAigu}[1]{\sbox0{#1}\dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 -1ex
  \sbox2{\'{}}\sbox1{\`{}}\sbox2{\raise\dimen0\box2}%
  {\ooalign{\hidewidth\kern-.05em\copy1\kern-.65\wd2\box2\hidewidth\cr\box0\crcr}}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{IPA}
\squareharp{u}
\textbara{}
\harp{e}
\harp{aa}
\GraveAigu{u}
\lowaigu{o}
aa{\Alif}

\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

FYI, here is the link to my previous question about African language symbols:[TIPA input for African language symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295751/tipa-input-for-african-language-symbols/295775?noredirect=1#comment715854_295775)

[image: problem report: l.26 aa{\Alif}?]

Comment: Where is the `Alif` package to be found?  It doesn't appear to be on CTAN.  Also, you mention the `semtrans` package but it's not anywhere in your sample document.  You should combine my document with the code that doesn't work into a single  (possibly non-working) document that shows the problem.  If I add `\usepackage{semtrans}` to my code, the `\Alif` command produces the same output as in a document without my code.

Comment: Thank you! I will post the combined codes in a new question.

Comment: Don't make a new question edit this one.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have edited the question, with the combined codes. Please let me know if it works for you. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the problem.  `\aa{\Alif}` yields å with the `\Alif` beside. What output are you expecting?  But `\aa` is not the same as `aa` (which is what you have in your first sample code, so the output will be different.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo--it should be aa{\Alif} in the combined code as well. So if I ran the combined code, it would not give me any output. It directed me to the line of  aa{\Alif}  and put a question mark, as if it did not recognize this symbol. I attached a screenshot of the problem report.

Comment: Load `semtrans` after loading `MnSymbol`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments