# Incorrect accent produced with \H{o}

Tags: fontspec, accents

Erd\H{o}s produces the following symbol instead of the slanted accent over o.[image]

Note: it is not typical latex output. Fontspec was used to change font and weight. Here is the code. I am currently using Erd"{o}s which produces a vertical accent instead of the slanted one. The output I would like is [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ModernMTStd-Extended.otf}[
FakeBold=2,
%SmallCapsFont=MrsEavesSmallCaps_Regular.ttf,
%BoldFont=Monotype-Modern-Std-Bold_31159.ttf,
ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
Ligatures=TeX,
]

\setsansfont[%
FakeBold=2,
ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf}

\setmonofont[%
FakeBold=2,
ItalicFont=NewCMMono10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCMMono10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCMMono10-BoldOblique.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}

%\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[FakeBold=2]
%\let\mathbb\mathbbalt

\begin{document}
    Erd\H{o}s
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full example so others have a chance to copy it and test for them self.

Comment: does the font have an H accent, eg does `\H{z}` work?  if not the question is essentially a duplicate of the automatically linked question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49313/poor-mans-double-acute-accent?rq=1

Comment: The answers in your linked question do not work in this case.

Comment: @Masum they must work, there was nothing specific to any font  but also are you using xetex or luatex (try both) and you did not answer anoy `\H{z}`

Comment: \H{z} did not work. I even tried $\text{Erd\H{o}s}$ and similar variations with no luck. I am using XeLaTeX as my default compiler.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could `fontenc` be messing with that?

Comment: @campa oops I dodn't even notice that!

Comment: remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` never use that with lualatex or xelatex. (although as you load fontspec afterwards fontspec will corect this error it will not do any harm  in this case.)

Comment: @campa I have tried both with and without `fontenc` and `lmodern`

Comment: Then you can use my answer in the linked question to use \H from a different font.

Comment: uh finally! only the augie one works and only when it is used with `\rmfamily`  inside \H. this is very weird that the other solutions do not work in this case. Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Flagged as duplicate to the question @DavidCarlisle linked

Comment: If the other part of that answer does not work presumably the fomt doesn't have the acute accent either, if it does not have an acute then faking \H with two accute accents and some space adjustment will not work.